# Derivative of Delta fuction?

Tags: differentiation, notation, dirac-delta-distributions

In *Shankar's Quantum Mechanics book* p-64 the last equation reads:
$$ \delta'(x'-x) = -\delta'(x-x'); $$

I am confused because if I think of it using the gaussian approximation then since: 
$$ g(x' -x) = \frac{1}{\Delta^2 \sqrt{\pi}} \exp\left[{-\frac{(x'-x)^2}{\Delta^2}} \right] $$
Which gives me:

$$ \frac{d}{dx'}  g(x'-x )=   \frac{d}{dx'}  g(x-x') $$
$$ \implies g'(x'-x) = g'(x-x') $$

How do I get the correct relation ?

**Edit: Adding the proof(?)**

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx'} g(x-x') & = \frac{d}{dx'} \left( \frac{1}{\Delta^2 \sqrt{\pi}} exp\left[{-\frac{(x-x')^2}{\Delta^2}} \right] \right)   \\
 & = g(x-x')\left( \frac{-1}{\Delta^2} \right) \frac{d}{dx'}\left( (x-x')^2 \right) \\
 & = g(x-x')\left( \frac{-1}{\Delta^2} \right) (2)(x'-x)
\end{align}

Similarly

\begin{align}
 \frac{d}{dx'} g(x'-x) & = \frac{d}{dx'} \left( \frac{1}{\Delta^2 \sqrt{\pi}} exp\left[{-\frac{(x'-x)^2}{\Delta^2}} \right] \right)   \\
 & = g(x'-x)\left( \frac{-1}{\Delta^2} \right) \frac{d}{dx'}\left( (x'-x)^2 \right) \\
 & = g(x'-x)\left( \frac{-1}{\Delta^2} \right) (2)(x'-x)
\end{align}

And since $ g(x-x')=g(x'-x)$ we get
$$ \frac{d}{dx'} g(x-x') =  \frac{d}{dx'} g(x'-x). $$

**Edit**
I found out the thing that was confusing me.

Comment: The "delta function" is even, so its derivative, if anything, must be odd.

Comment: @hyportnex  delta function is even only when we flip sign of both $ x $ and $x'$ . Flipping $x'$ sign alone doesnt work. :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write $x-x'=y$, then use the chain rule
$$
\frac d{dx'} f(x-x') = \frac {dy}{dx'} \frac{d}{dy}f(y)= (-1 )\frac{d}{dy}f(y)=-f'(y)=- f'(x-x')
$$

Answer (score 10):

The derivative you take is not over the argument, it is over $x'$ in particular. For your last line, the chain rule should be used to get

$$\frac{d}{dx} g(-x) = -g'(-x)$$

instead.

Comment: Sorry,I dont understand  why would we use chain rule for differentiating $g(x-x') $ wrt $x'$ . Could you be more explicit? Basically I took the gaussian function and differentiated it wrt $x'$ .

Comment: In the conclusion of your question below "Which gives me", you wrote (both times the RHS): $\frac{d}{dx^\prime}g(x-x^\prime)=g^\prime(x-x^\prime)$, where you are missing a minus sign because of the chain rule.

Comment: @ProgrammingMachine5000 I understand chain rule as the other answer shows. I have edited the part I am not getting.

Comment: @1elektron Everything up to the end of your edit is correct; it's the step *after* that that is wrong.